# Trying to use if function in the middle of echo

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I'm trying to do.

There are two `columns` in my table. One called `PriceMin`, and One Called `PriceMax`.

---

Now some `rows` of the `table` have a `PriceMax` and some **don't.**

---

I'm trying to echo both columns in one on the front end.

For `echo`ing them in the table, I need to seperate the ones that do have a `PriceMax` value with a `-` or my price column in html would have a `-` after every each price, no matter if they have a `PriceMax` or not which is not a good idea.

---

I thought this could be achieved with the isset or empty function.

I've tried the following:

Saved as a seperate file, and include in the `echo` function:

Function:

```
if (empty($row["PriceMax"])) {
    echo "";    
} else {  
    echo "-";
}
```

Echo line:

```
$putdash = include ('iffunction.php');
$dbtable = '<tr><td>' .$name. '</td><td>' .$row["PriceMin"].$putdash.$row["PriceMax"] '</td></tr>';
```

This did not work. What options do I have to have a `function` check for the presence of `$row["PriceMax"]` and `echo` a `-`?

Thanks for any help I might get !

Comment: What is the rest of the code around that if statement? You are in a for loop I imagine, so this would look something like `$row[$i]["PriceMax"]` if that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ternary operator, http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators, to set the value to a variable. You don't actually want to output/echo it there.

```
$putdash = empty($row["PriceMax"]) ? "" : "-";
$dbtable = '<tr><td>' .$name. '</td><td>' .$row["PriceMin"].$putdash.$row["PriceMax"] . '</td></tr>';
```

Demo: https://eval.in/409912